# Error when freezing pandas/NumPy 1.7.0 code with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze a Python script with cx_Freeze. The script makes use of pandas. When I run the executable created by cx_Freeze, I get the following Traceback:

```
[...]  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>  
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib  
File "ExtensionLoader_pandas_hashtable.py", line 11, in <module>  
File "numpy.pxd", line 156, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:20273)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>  
from core import *  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sys'
```

The only pandas code I am using (for testing) is:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
     'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}
df = DataFrame(d)
```

When I try to include 'pandas' under 'packages' in the cx_Freeze setup file, it fails during the freeze process with:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I have encountered this same issue for 32 and 64 bit versions of Python 2.7.3 on Windows7 (64bit). pandas version is 0.10.1 and cx_Freeze is 4.3.1.

Does anybody of you pandas or cx_Freeze gods have an idea?

Comment: Is that `ValueError` from freezing, or from running the frozen code? Is there a traceback with it?

Comment: That is the Traceback during freezing, I should be able to post the full Traceback later today.

Comment: If it ends like [this traceback](https://gist.github.com/takluyver/4501992), it's a [bug someone else encountered](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/16/failure-in-strange-code-path), but I've not been able to reproduce. Possibly a Windows specific bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just looked at the /numpy/core/**init**.py and noticed at the second last line:

there is "del sys"

if you comment out this line, it works as expected. I also noticed there was no "del sys" in numpy 1.6.2

you may try to contact numpy to check why they need to do this.

Comment: Perfect, this works! thanks a lot. You still need to list 'numpy' under 'packages' though.

Comment: Hi Felix I use includes=['numpy'] instead. like: options = dict(compressed=True,includes=['numpy'],excludes=['Tkinter','tcl','ttk','tkinter'],optimize=2), setup(
        name = "numpybug",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze script",
        options=dict(build_exe=options),
        executables = executables) It works for me.

Comment: Hi Felix, just let you know I have posted a note on numpy mail list and there is a person submitted a patch for cx_freeze later on. link is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/bugs/36/ hope it is useful.

Comment: Wow - thanks a lot! I am also pasting your discussion on the numpy mailing list for reference: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2013-February/065589.html

Comment: They do that because any name that is in `__init__.py` will be imported when you do `from numpy.core import *`, and it's not good to have that pollute the namespace with non-NumPy names like `sys` (a better fix would be to use `__all__`, though).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for both errors seem to be `NumPy 1.7.0` (pandas builds on NumPy). When I run the code with `NumPy 1.6.2`, everything works.

Comment: @ThomasK would you be able to have a look at my minimalistic [code sample](https://gist.github.com/fzumstein/5007372) to give me a hint why NumPy 1.7.0 is failing while 1.6.2 is not? Thanks

Comment: When I copy the `numpy` folder manually into the build folder, it works. However, by listing it under `'packages':['numpy']` doesn't help.