# Is NumPy Messing Up CX_Freeze?

Tags: python, numpy, cx-freeze

I'm trying to run a frozen python game I've coded but I get an error when I try to run the exe. I believe its because of NumPy but I'm not quite sure. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "game.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 251, in <module>

    try: import pygame.surfarray
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\surfarray.py", line 69, in <module>

    import pygame._numpysurfarray as numpysf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\_numpysurfarray.py", line 48, in <m
odule>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from core import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sys'
```

Does anyone know whats going on here cause I cant figure it out?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Nate

Comment: "I'm trying to a frozen python game" - What are you trying to do with the game?

Comment: What versions of everything? There have been multiple bugs with cx_freeze and numpy, and without knowing what versions of Python, cx_freeze, and numpy you have, there's no way of knowing which fixes you need and which you have. Alternatively, you might want to try using the [development version of cx_freeze](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze) to see if the problem goes away. Also, have you read the Related posts on the right, or searched the site for similar questions?

Comment: @user2357112: If you read the rest of the sentence, he already says he needs to cod it, which means either (1) to fish for cod, (2) to fish as with cod nets, or (3) to deceive or confuse. The first two are nonsense, so clearly he's trying to deceive his code, and wrapping it up in cx_freeze is just his first step, lulling it into a false sense of companionship. :)

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 32 bit, cx freeze 4.3.1 32 bit for python 2.7 and NumPy 1.7.1 32 bit for python 2.7. If you can figure this out it would be greatly appreciated! @abarnert

Comment: I previously asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969552/error-when-freezing-pandas-numpy-1-7-0-code-with-cx-freeze

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in cx_Freeze, which should be fixed in the development version.

The problem is discussed [here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/a-question-about-freeze-on-numpy-1-7-0-td32954.html), and here's [the pull request to fix it](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/17/avoid-polluting-extension-module-namespace/diff).