# cx_freeze fails to build numpy executable

Tags: python, numpy, enthought, cx-freeze

I am using the `cx_freeze` development version (as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321727/is-numpy-messing-up-cx-freeze), also tried latest stable 1.3.1) and I try to build an executable for windows from a file that imports numpy and an Enthought Canopy distribution. This is the file `test.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):

    y = np.linspace(0,x,1000)
    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print f(5)
```

This is the setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = None

setup(  name = "foo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("test.py", base=base)])
```

This is the error I get when running the exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\cx_
freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-win32.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <mod
ule>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\lib\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\lib\polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\linalg\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "C:\Users\Zah\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\num
py\linalg\linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
  File "ExtensionLoader_numpy_linalg_lapack_lite.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_numpy_linalg_lapack_lite.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.
```

I notice there is a `numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.pyd` file in the build directory.

Comment: did you find the answer? could help me alot

Comment: Ended up using PyInstaller. It was a pain as well, but worked in the end.

Comment: yea, I just figure it out with pyinstaller too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Python installation directory, go to the Scripts directory (i.e C:/Python27/Scripts). In this folder you should find two DLL files:

1. mk2_core.dll
2. mk2iomp5md.dll

Edit your cxFreeze build routine such that these two files are copied to the same directory as your executable (your build directory). After that, try running the exe, this should fix the problem (it did for me anyway).

---

How did I figure this out? You said you noticed the numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.p.yd file. What I did was I opened this file using a tool called DependencyWalker ([website](http://www.DependencyWalker.com)). This program analyzes all the DLL dependency a file has. Upon analysis, it told me that those two DLL files were missing.

I really do hope that this helps, I know how frustrating these things can be!

Comment: I can't find any of these files (mk2_core.dll or mk2iomp5md.dll) in the Scripts directory (i.e C:/Python27/Scripts), or any other directory in my computer.